# How to flatten nested array json in snowflake

Tags: json, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I'm receiving multiple JSON files and loading them into a Snowflake variant field. I would like to then extract some of the child arrays into a separate table but am having issues with that. Here is an example of the JSON:

```
"ParentArray": [
    {
      "ParentId": "116fb319-36ea-4148",
      "make": "*",
      "ChildArray": [
        {
          "id": "1ed464e0-8ed7",
          "value": "18500 Studebaker Rd"
        },
        {
          "id": "1ed464e0-95d0-66a6",
          "value": "90703"
        },
        ],
      "status": 1,
      "Condition": "*"
      ]
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your example, something like this would parse out the array for your ChildArray.  If you update your question with a more specific expected output, I can update the answer, but ultimately, you are looking for a lateral flatten command.

```
with x as (
    select parse_json('{"ParentArray": [
    {
      "ParentId": "116fb319-36ea-4148",
      "make": "*",
      "ChildArray": [
        {
          "id": "1ed464e0-8ed7",
          "value": "18500 Studebaker Rd"
        },
        {
          "id": "1ed464e0-95d0-66a6",
          "value": "90703"
        },
        ],
      "status": 1,
      "Condition": "*"
      }]
    }') as var
)
select y.value:id::string as id, y.value:value::string as value
from x,
lateral flatten(input=>x.var:ParentArray[0]:ChildArray) y;
```

Note: I had to make a couple of minor changes to your example JSON to make it proper JSON.